# Error in couch DB along using with fabric composer

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

[image]

The `$syscollectionsAsset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.Identity` document does not exist.
I have used UUID function in my fabric composer example (logic.js). I am getting error in couch DB like above
when i click on any row it is showing error. Is it related to UUID function or what?
please ans me

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: yes,I have resolved it.